# Generating multiple indexes in a single postgres table

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have some source syntax that I need to convert from MySQL to postgreSQL. It seems that there is no analog in postgres for generating multiple indexes on a single table. Also, I am having trouble understanding why one would generate multiple indexes on a single table:

```
ALTER TABLE concept 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (table_id), 
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_table_table_id (table_id), 
  ADD INDEX idx_table_code (table_code), 
  ADD INDEX idx_table_v_id (v_id), 
  ADD INDEX idx_cd_id (d_id), 
  ADD INDEX idx_table_class_id (table_class_id);
```

any ideas?

Comment: Usually you create unique constraints instead of unique indexes. Well... unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL each constraint is added separately. See [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

Your single DDL (Data Definition Language) statement needs to be broken down into:

- **Constraints** keep data in check according to rules:

  ```
   ALTER TABLE concept ADD PRIMARY KEY (table_id);
  ```
- **Indexes** are useful to speed up *some* queries. Use carefully:

  ```
   CREATE INDEX idx_table_code ON concept (table_code);

   CREATE INDEX idx_table_v_id ON concept (v_id);

   CREATE INDEX idx_cd_id ON concept (d_id);

   CREATE INDEX idx_table_class_id ON concept (table_class_id);
  ```

  **Note:** Create indexes only when you need them. My [very personal] rule of thumb is not to exceed 10 for each table. If I get to that level, then I need to reconsider carefully what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could break it into separate statements. Note also that creating a primary key will implicitly create a unique index on that column, so you shouldn't attempt to explicitly create one too:

```
ALTER TABLE concept ADD PRIMARY KEY (table_id); 
ALTER TABLE concept ADD INDEX idx_table_code (table_code);
ALTER TABLE concept ADD INDEX idx_table_v_id (v_id);
ALTER TABLE concept ADD INDEX idx_cd_id (d_id);
ALTER TABLE concept ADD INDEX idx_table_class_id (table_class_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As somebody said earlier, you should make a CREATE INDEX statement per each index.

About the multiple index on a table... the issue is that sometimes the queries on a single table could be very different. On  your example, is not the same make a sql with the predicate based on table_code column or based on d_id column.

That's why sometimes the better is make a separate index for both. Maybe seems easier and better make a single index for both columns but you should think that the order of the index columns is very important and even more if both columns have a lot of different values. Also not always both table_code or d_id columns could be on the sqls.